# How to select next duplicate selection in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio

In pretty much all other IDE's I have used there is a keybinding to select the next occurrence of the selected code I have highlighted. Say it is

`p = new Program();`

And I have `new` highlighted if I pressed that keybinding it would highlight and place a caret at that next occurrence.

Is there any keybinding like this in Visual Studio? I have searched all over and looked through the keyboard settings but can't seem to find anything like this.

Answer (score 2):

I found it,

Edit.InsertNextMatchingCaret (Shift+Alt+. (Text Editor))